# What are some good uses for custom live CDs

Tags: live-cd, custom-distributions

Looking for some good uses for your own custom live CD/distro, including custom branded distributions for Cafes etc.

You can include instructions etc in your answer, as well as links to good examples. However, please limit ONE example per answer - though feel free to answer multiple times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another cool idea is to create a distro (obviously based on Ubuntu) where you can use it for a kiosk PC.
For example, you need to set-up a PC where people will be able to search books on a library only typing the name of the book on a touchpad screen.
The main thing is create this distro with:

- A minimal install
- A browser (like firefox)
- A browser's addon to create this kiosk mode ( like [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/) addons for firefox)
- Apache and (if is necessary) a DBMS

Its really easy to set-up and you can use in several cases
For example

- In a Restaurant (where persons can see their reservations)
- In a cofee shop (You can order your coffee directly in the system)

Answer (score 1):

One good idea is a stripped down recovery CD, containing the tools you need to check drives, perform backups, and chroot into the system to perform fixes.

Method:

- Install Ubuntu Minimal (in a virtual machine)
- Add the [remastersys](http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/) repository and install remastersys.
- Install openbox and any commandline tools you need.
- Install gnome-terminal/a terminal of your choice.
- Install a file manager.
- Run remastersys in dist- mode to create your live CD.
- Have a big party with friends to show them how awesome you are, and hand out free copies of your new recovery system!